# Using 3 different tables to query

Tags: mysql, join

This is my first post, I apologize if I didn't include the correct information or if formatting was off.
I want to determine **what restaurants are popular in what city among the customer orders**.

There is one other table: customers
Customers table includes *id (PK),first name, last name, city_id(FK), email*

Restaurants table:

| id | restaurant_name | Address | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Taco Bell | 30269 W 8th Street, Los Angeles, CA | 1 |
| 2 | Subway | 1728 S Western Avenue, Los Angeles, CA | 1 |
| 3 | McDonald's | 1100 Fillmore Street,San Francisco, CA | 3 |
| 4 | Wendy's | 200 SW 8th Street, Miami, FL | 4 |
| 5 | JR Sushi | 86 W Broadway, New York, NY | 2 |

City table:

| id | city_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Los Angeles |
| 2 | New York |
| 3 | San Francisco |
| 4 | Miami |

delivery_orders table:

| order_id | order_time | customer_id | restaurant_id | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-12 12:04:32 | 1 | 3 | 25.75 |
| 2 | 2020-06-18 20:20:19 | 2 | 1 | 32.68 |
| 3 | 2022-09-12 16:23:16 | 3 | 3 | 27.53 |

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT restaurants.name, city.name, COUNT(*) AS popular_restaurant
FROM restaurants
INNER JOIN city
ON restaurants.city_id = city.id
INNER JOIN delivery_orders
ON delivery_orders.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id
GROUP BY restaurants.name, city.name
HAVING COUNT(restaurants.name) > 0
ORDER BY popular_restaurant DESC;
```

It outputs the restaurant names, city names, and a popular_restaurant count. However, the city names are repeated multiple times. I only want the most popular restaurant in each city based on delivery_orders table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to limit the number of rows returned per city, the first example is literally only one row per city:

```
WITH popular_restaurants AS (
    SELECT city, restaurant, COUNT(*) AS popularity_score,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM delivery_orders
    GROUP BY city, restaurant
)
SELECT city, restaurant, popularity_score
FROM popular_restaurants
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If however, you wish to list "equal top" restaurants, then use dense_rank() [*or rank()*]

```
WITH popular_restaurants AS (
    SELECT city, restaurant, COUNT(*) AS popularity_score,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rank
    FROM delivery_orders
    GROUP BY city, restaurant
)
SELECT city, restaurant, popularity_score
FROM popular_restaurants
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Note, to get other attributes such as restaurant name, join the needed table(s) in the final select, the joined tables are unnecessary in the group by query.

Also note that when using row_number(), dense_rank() or rank() that you can "fine tune" the results by adding to the `order by` clause. In particular note that descending order of the count is used in both examples. Perhaps more relevant the first example above you could add some "tie-breaker" logic to e.g. `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, restaurant`. If you wanted to decide by restaurant name, then you would need to join tables within the group by query.